# Billing of Jinja2 entities retrievement

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

When retrieving entities from ndb via jinja2 like

{% ent.rel.get().property %}

Does it count as a read in billing?
Does it use cached values ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats will help find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Jinja2 is just one of many templating systems for Python.

What you're doing in the given example is just retrieving a previously rendered value in your template, usually when executing the following lines:

```
template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('foo.html')
request.response.write(template.render(template_data))
```

This causes no "reading costs", but in order to do this rendering you previously had to retrieve your data either from Datastore or Memcache within your Python code, which will be charged according to the [Datastore Calls pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#costs-for-datastore-calls), only in case you already exceeded the free daily quota (stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore)).